# How to join a string value from a tag with a string value from a field?

Tags: influxdb-2, fluxlang

consider having the following line protocol data:

```
my_measurement,foo="Some" bar="Thing",baz=123
```

where `foo` is a tag and `bar` and `baz` are fields, I need to get, say,
a string `"Some|Thing"` out of *InfluxDB OSS v2* using the *Flux* language.
What's the trick? How to do it? There is the `strings.joinStr()`
and the `keyValues()` functions I feel could be perhaps used to get the desired
values but I failed to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with map(), for example:

```
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with newColName: r.foo+r._bar}))
```

Or, if you have to convert the type of _field,

```
|> map(fn: (r) => ({r with newColName: r.foo+string(v: r._baz)}))
```